# Bootable Flash Drive

Tags: 10.04, laptop, flash, drive

I have reinstalled ubuntu 10.04.3 on my laptop and would like to make a bootable flash drive either from netbooks or 11.1 version since my new netbook has built in camera and speaker, however when I use the download procedure from ubuntu page it expects me to use the Start Up Disk which 10.04 does not have. I even tried to get it from link that is provided to no avail. So how do i download this software to my 16 GB flash drive with 7.7 GB free space in order to install it on my netbook please? English is my second language and am none technical by the way. Thank you, Sa'ed

Comment: FYI, you will have to format your flash drive before you can make it bootable, you may want to consider A: backing up your flash drive or B: using a different one.

Comment: ***Please clarify:***  What are you downloading, and to achieve what?  Are you trying to install **Ubuntu 11.10** on the 16GB flash (SD card?), for dual boot (alongside **10.04.3 LTS**)?  Or, do you just want to upgrade, to better support inbuilt camera and speakers?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download iso for Ubuntu 11.10 (either 64 bit or 32 bit) from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download OR download 10.04 from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download
2. Open a program called Startup Disk Creator (It should be installed by default it not then open synaptic package manager search for it and install)
3. Create bootable USB from downloaded iso and ur flash drive.

Boot any computer with ur live USB disk.

Enjoy :D

Comment: If Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't have startup-disk-creator installed, and if you can't find and install it using Synaptic, then there must be some other program that provides the same function as startup-disk-creator. I have used it in 10.04.

Comment: that would be uNetBooting

Answer (score 0):

Before you try anything you may want to back-up any data you have on that usb stick/flash drive.  Once you do you could use gparted (it's in the Ubuntu Software Center) to partition the drive.  Then make sure you install onto the right partition on the usb stick/flash drive.  Hopefully the whole drive doesn't get reformatted by the "Usb disk creator".  But even if it does you have it backed up so just put you're data back onto the partition not used by Ubuntu's installer.

The "Disk Creator" in 10.04 is under the Administration menu.  I haven't used 10.04 in a while but if I remember correctly it was labeled "USB Start-up disk creator" or something close. Download the ISO (that's the format that Ubuntu downloads in) onto your hard drive and use the "usb disk creator" to install it onto your flash drive/usb stick.